# Blocking Bluemail from EWS/EAS

Tags: exchange

I'm dumbstruck right now. All mail clients that use Activesync are quarantined and have to be approved by our helpdesk. Yet, we came across some mail clients that were still able to bypass this on mobile phones and the most notable one was BlueMail. After some research, you learn that it uses EWS so I enabled the EWS Block list org wide and added BlueMail* as value. But mail keeps on flowing.

For those wondering, org-wide we have EwsEnabled set to $null with the EwsApplicationAccessPolicy set to EnforceBlockList. I also attempted to apply the block on my own account to see if it could have been an issue with the org-wide setting, but that also did not block the app.

So I started troubleshooting furter and only when I blocked ActiveSync on my mail account did BlueMail stop connecting to our on-prem mail server.

This creates 2 questions for me:

- How is it going through EAS without tripping the quarantine?
- How can we block it properly in a way that will also work on Exchange Online? This excludes things like blocking it on the load balancer, as after migration to EXO, that will no longer be in play.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information. It seems all your settings are correct, when you blocked the ActiveSync on your server, then bluemail would not be able to connect to your server.

According to this situation, the bluemail on mobile is still use the EAS to connect to server.

You can control the mobile access based on the device type/device module.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/controlling-exchange-activesync-device-access-using-the-allow/ba-p/588930

It should work same on exchange online.